# I am confused on how to implement singleton pattern to my code and get it to call on my object classes and methods

Tags: java, class, design-patterns

As the title suggest, I'm trying to implement the singleton design pattern to my code. My code has a main class and 3 inherited classes. I would like to create only one object that is able to use all of the functions in the code. This is my first time dealing with design patterns so my code might be everywhere. Here is the code:

```
class geniusATM {

    private String name, address;
    private int pin, ficoScore;
    double checkingBalance, savingBalance, mortgageBalance;

    public geniusATM() {

    }

    geniusATM(String nam, String addr, int pn, int fs, double cB, double sB, double mB) {
        name = nam;
        address = addr;
        ficoScore = fs;
        checkingBalance = cB;
        savingBalance = sB;
        mortgageBalance = mB;
    }

         //setters and getters are here
        }

       class Checkings extends geniusATM {
        //stuff here
          }

       class Savings extends geniusATM {
        //stuff here
         }

       class billPay extends Checkings {
       //stuff here

       }

     public class singletonObject {

      private static singletonObject ob;

    private  singletonObject() {
        geniusATM matt = new geniusATM("Matt", "124 Road Drive.", 1234, 3462, 560.00, 500.50, 472.29);

    }

    public static singletonObject getObject() {
        if (ob == null) {
            ob = new singletonObject();
        }
        return ob;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }


}
```

Comment: That is one way to create a singleton. You should probably make geniusATM a class variable instead of a constructor one, so it can be used by other methods in the singleton.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: In general there are three ways to implement a singleton in java. They are all explained in the effective java book (which i highly recommend). Here you can read a short description about them https://medium.com/codelog/3-methods-to-create-singleton-with-java-effective-java-learning-notes-12ee8cd27ccd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now with the ob variable you can get the all function that crated in any class from the 4 classes

```
class geniusATM {

private String name, address;
private int pin, ficoScore;
double checkingBalance, savingBalance, mortgageBalance;

public geniusATM() {

}

geniusATM(String nam, String addr, int pn, int fs, double cB, double sB, double mB) {
    name = nam;
    address = addr;
    ficoScore = fs;
    checkingBalance = cB;
    savingBalance = sB;
    mortgageBalance = mB;
}

     //setters and getters are here
    }

   class Checkings extends geniusATM {
       public Checkings() {

}
     Checkings (String nam, String addr, int pn, int fs, double cB, double sB, double mB) {super( nam, addr,  pn,  fs,cB, sB, mB);}
      }

   class Savings extends Checkings {
       public Savings() {

}
     Savings (String nam, String addr, int pn, int fs, double cB, double sB, double mB) {super( nam, addr,  pn,  fs,cB, sB, mB);}
      }


   class billPay extends Savings {
       public billPay() {

}
   billPay (String nam, String addr, int pn, int fs, double cB, double sB, 
double mB) {super( nam, addr,  pn,  fs,cB, sB, mB);}
      }


 public class singletonObject {

  private static Checkings ob;

private  singletonObject () {
    billPay matt = new billPay ("Matt", "124 Road Drive.", 1234, 3462, 560.00, 500.50, 472.29);

}

public static Checkings getObject() {
    if (ob == null) {
        ob = new billPay();
    }
    return ob;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


}
```

}

Comment: So I implemented your code into mine and in the main I tried to call ob.balance();
it caused an exception where it says java.lang.NullPointerException in java. Am I calling the object wrong?

Comment: the op in the first places will be null until you call the function getObject

Comment: you can write in main something like this billPay temp =(billPay)getObject();
   System.out.println(temp.checkingBalance);

Comment: Okay thank you, I have a jFrame for my GUI, I'm trying to call billPay temp =(billPay)getObject() but it says getObject() cant be found. Any way I can fix that?

Comment: Ignore my previous question. I'm trying to call singletonObject sinOb = singletonObject.getObject(); 
It gives an error that checkings cant be forced into singleton. I try to change getObject to singletonObject but it causes more issues. I'm not sure how to resolve it. Thank you

Comment: yeah it will give you error because singletonObject  is not from type geniusATM ,, make singletonObject extends   geniusATM  and it will work ,, please make my answer as accepted answer if it useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Using java naming conventions and @Dvorog suggestion...

```
public class GeniusAtm() {

    private static GeniusAtm gAtm;

    private geniusATM() {

    }

    public static GeniusAtm instance() {
      if(null == gAtm) {
         gAtm = new GeniusAtm();
      }

      return gAtm;
    }

    //Your other methods here
}
```

If you want to use your example on ways to access children through the singleton, you're going to have to do something that is ugly like this...

```
public class GeniusAtm {

    private String name, address;
    private int pin, fico;
    private double checkingBalance, savingsBalance, mortgageBalance;
    private static GeniusAtm geniusAtm;
    private Checkings checking;

    private GeniusAtm (String name, String address, int pin, int fico, double checkingBalance, double savingsBalance, double mortgageBalance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.pin = pin;
        this.fico = fico;
        this.checkingBalance = checkingBalance;
        this.savingsBalance = savingsBalance;
        this.mortgageBalance = mortgageBalance;

        checking = new Checkings(name,address,pin,fico,checkingBalance,savingsBalance,mortgageBalance);
    }

    public static GeniusAtm instance() {
        if(null == geniusAtm) {
            geniusAtm = new GeniusAtm("Matt", "124 Road Drive.", 1234, 3462, 560.00, 500.50, 472.29);
        }

        return geniusAtm;
    }

    private class Checkings extends GeniusAtm {

        Checkings(String name, String address, int pin, int fico, double checkingBalance, double savingsBalance, double mortgageBalance) {
            super(name,address,pin,fico,checkingBalance,savingsBalance,mortgageBalance);
        }

        public void updateName(String name) {

        }
    }

    //OTHER IMPLEMENTATIONS HERE

    public Checkings getCheckings() {
        return checking;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GeniusAtm atm = GeniusAtm.instance();

        atm.getCheckings().updateName("That Guy");
    }
}
```

However, I would never suggesting doing anything like that in any practical sense primarily because of the redundancy and the lack of adherence to OOP inheritance and composition concepts. Is it possible you want an `Person`, an `Account`, and maybe a `Fico` object? In which case your `Account` would be your singleton. There are several different ways to do this, but the implementation with the subclasses you have of GeniusAtm, is not something I would recommend.

Comment: `static private GeniusAtm gAtm;` and `static public GeniusAtm instance() {`

Comment: So this class wont have any fields (like name, pin...etc) If so, how do I call on them in this class and get it to inherit that information to the subclasses?

Comment: I revised the answer a bit to fit your question, however, I'm not suggesting you build it that way by any means.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using java class naming conventions your class should be `GeniusAtm` (a class name should start with uppercase letter and be a noun e.g. `String`, `Color`, `System`, etc.)

To apply the singleton pattern in this class you will need to set your constructor as `private` and create a `getInstance()` method. This method checks whether an instance of this object has already been created. If it is true, it returns this instance, otherwise it creates a new instance and then return it.

It will be something like this:

```
public class GeniusAtm {
    private static GeniusAtm instance; // singleton instance here

    private String name, address;
    private int pin, ficoScore;
    double checkingBalance, savingBalance, mortgageBalance;

    private geniusATM() {

    }

    public static synchronized GeniusAtm getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new GeniusAtm();
        return instance;
    }

    // other stuffs
}
```

The `synchronized` ensures that the `getInstance()` will be thread safe.

Comment: Okay thank you, how would I set this object fields and call on it in main?

Comment: @HenryReichard Like normal object, with gettet and setters. But instead of calling the constructor (`new GeniusAtm()`), you would call the `static` `getInstance()` method. Something like this: `GeniusAtm geniusAtm = GeniusAtm.getInstance();`

Comment: @Glim - I prefer the pattern `private static GeniusAtm instance = new GeniusAtm();` ... then `getInstance()` becomes just `return instance;` You don't have to check if `instance == null` because the instance is created just once, still as a static, when the class is first loaded.  The class is only loaded when you reference it, so it's not even much of a Lazy vs. Eager loading debate.

Comment: @StephenP that's true. But I think that my example is also good to illustrate generically the `singleton` concept.